# How to Add Usercontrols on a specific position in a TableLayoutpanel

Tags: c#, user-controls, tablelayoutpanel

Team.

I have a Problem with my Tablelayoutpanel. The Tablelayoutpanel is located in the Main-Form and filled with 5 Usercontrols (5 equal Controls, filled with other texts). 
Every Usercontrol contains a button. If I click on that button in the UC, 10 other Usercontrols should be added AFTER the clicked Usercontrol.

My Code so far (In the Button-Click Method):

```
private void bt_Öffnen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ziele = getZielStatement();

        foreach (var z in ziele.Where(z => z.Hauptziele.PerspektivenID == gl_PerspektiveID)) // Für jedes Ziel in der jeweiligen Perspektive
        {             
            Uc_Ziele uc_ziel = new Uc_Ziele();
            uc_ziel.gl_Unterziel = z;
            this.Parent.Controls.Add(uc_ziel);               
        }
    }
```

The problem is, that the Controls are added at the end of TableLayoutpanel. They should be added after the clicked Usercontrol.

I cant do it without help. Hope you get what i want.

Greets, Daniel

Answer (score 0):

After you've added the control use the SetChildIndex method to move it to its correct position.

Check out this post for further info

[How to add rows into middle of a TableLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964239/how-to-add-rows-into-middle-of-a-tablelayoutpanel?rq=1)